# How do I get the text in a paragraph element to stop overflowing the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make the text in the `<p>` tag wrap in its container, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. It overflows its container and I can't figure out why.

Essentially the sport div contains two divs, title and info and each of the child divs takes 50% of the sports divs space. The paragraph in the title div is supposed to have centered text that wraps in the paragraph container.

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.title p {
  font-size: 70px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title span {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 230, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 230, 0, 0) 16%, rgb(255, 230, 0) 16%, rgb(251, 255, 0) 41%, rgba(255, 238, 0, 0) 41%);
  padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.1em;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="sports section">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>SPORTS</h1>
    <p class="sport heading"><span>random piece of text that doesn't wrap</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="img-cont">
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: What sort of layout are you after? Do you want the paragraph element to expand? It's generally not ideal to use paragraphs as flex layout containers in the first place. Usually I prefer to keep content and presentation separate.

Comment: i just want the text to to wrap in the paragraph container, i want the text to always be centralized

Comment: the big text is part of the aesthetic i'm going for, and it'd fit if the text would wrap in the container. any ideas?

Comment: We're waiting for you to describe the overall page layout you're after. Without knowing that it's hard to offer advice. There's more to this than just overflow and text wrap.

Comment: well essentially the sport div contains two divs, title and info and each of the child divs takes 50% of the sports divs space. the paragraph in the title div is supposed to have centered text that wraps around the paragraph container.

Comment: When you say that each inner container should take 50% of the space, what do you mean? You want equal-height rows?

Comment: Let's try this. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/p20cas4v/) that simplifies your scenario. What needs to change with it?  (Part of the problem was that your paragraph background gradient wasn't full height, giving the false impression that the text was overflowing the paragraph.)

Comment: thank you very much for your help, you didn't put the span in the fiddle though. after googling a bit i gound the answer in any case

Answer (score 1):

well i found a hacky way around it (not necessarily hacky but i can't figure out why this is the soluton), all i had to do was add 'white-space: normal' amd it started wrapping inside the container. it messed with the design i was using the span tag for though, so i got rid of it because it wasn't essential and was always kind of buggy. :

```css
.title p {
    font-size: 70px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
    }
```

`

so to update this i removed the 'display:flex' from the paragraph and just used a normal text align to center it and now the span element works, i don't know why it suddenly works because i'd tried this a couple of times but it does.

```css
.title p {
    font-size: 70px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

div class="sports section" => text-align: center;

div class="title"          => margin: auto;

```css
.sports.section {
text-align: center;
}
.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  
    margin: auto;
}

.title p {
  font-size: 70px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title span {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 230, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 230, 0, 0) 16%, rgb(255, 230, 0) 16%, rgb(251, 255, 0) 41%, rgba(255, 238, 0, 0) 41%);
  padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.1em;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="sports section">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>SPORTS</h1>
    <p class="sport heading"><span>random piece of text that doesn't wrap</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="img-cont">
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Auto margins aren't necessary with a flex layout. Flexbox has mechanisms for that. At any rate, the paragraph doesn't contain its text, which is the problem that needs a solution.